# Loading .dae in Three.js using ColladaLoader.js from Mixamo

Tags: javascript, three.js, collada

I'm not able to load a .dae file into my Three.js scene. I have a working .dae from a tutorial that loads, but when I replace the file with my .dae I get the following errors (attached)[image]

I tried loading it in the three.js/editor and it does not load.
The file came from Adobe's Mixamo program.
I'm using the ColladaLoader.js from r75 as well as three.js from r75

Thanks!

Comment: Collada is open Source format but the xml have lots different content as per the software it is exported (3DS max,Maya ,adobe). Try to import that collada into blender and then export as collada again then try with your usual process.
one more thing this uncaught err is beacuse one of the vector is coming undefine.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I imported my .dae into blender then re-exported, but Three.js still wont display it. Here is the .dae file that works: https://gist.github.com/evejweinberg/aad2dd6e0b391113451d06f165126db0
and the one that I WANT to work, from blender: https://gist.github.com/evejweinberg/5dee006b2faa6b7e5a6ec6dea1b289c4

Comment: I have the same problem using free dae from mixamo. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I finally got a .dae working in Three.js from mixamo. I didn't change anything about my mixamo export process, I just updated to Revision '82dev' (the current one) and the example called 'webgl_loader_collada.html' worked (All other webgl_loader_collada examples did not work, the 'skinning, 'kinematic' and 'keyframe' still do not work). The console is filled with warnings though, fyi.